# write mail with mutt using emacs

Tags: email, emacs, word-wrap, mutt

I am using both mutt and emacs to write mail.

I use, until recent time, this code into my .emacs :

```
; corrector
(add-hook 'mail-mode-hook 'flyspell-mode)

; Do not cut words
(global-visual-line-mode t)

; open mail-mode when emacs is invoked by mutt                                
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("/mutt" . mail-mode))

; wrap email body
(add-hook 'mail-mode-hook 'turn-on-auto-fill)
(add-hook 'mail-mode-hook 'turn-on-filladapt-mode)
```

But it is not working anymore. When I write a email with emacs I have no flyspell enable and the mail-mode does not wrap the text.

When I try to launch the mail-mode manually, I have a error :

```
File mode specification error: (void-function turn-on-filladapt-mode)
Making completion list... [2 times]
run-hooks: Symbol's function definition is void: turn-on-filladapt-mode
```

Comment: Was this code working recently?  It seems like you have not filladapt available anymore.  Did you upgrade anything of your system?  Did you modify your .emacs?  Is "emacs --debug-init" reporting any problem?

Comment: yes I upgrade my system (new machine and new os (debian sid). This configuration used to work on debian stable on another machine. Maybe I have a package missing? But I couldn't say which one.

Comment: You need to install filladapt, or remove the last line of your config.  And you need to make sure that "emacs --debug-init" does not complain about anything in your setup.  Also, you need to make sure that on the new system the "/mutt" substring is still valid for mail buffers.

Comment: Thanks installing filladapt (package emacs-goodies.el) in debian fix the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was caused by the missing package emacs-goodies.el (in debian sid) which include filladapt.